# How to test wireless connection speed using java?

Tags: java, performance, wifi

In my compiler how would I test wireless connection speed from a computer?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by compiler? I think you meant to say from IDE like Eclipse and you would have to write code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading a file from the internet and simply use a start/end timer

```
Long start = System.nanoTime();

// download to file code goes here
URL website = new URL("http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.0.2/jersey-client-1.0.2.jar");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

// do some validation check here that the file is successfully downloaded
Long end = System.nanoTime();
// and then measure time. you get file size (bytes) which you can use to measure speed
```

Also worth reading about Neflix fast.com implementation [here](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/building-fast-com-4857fe0f8adb)